# Programmatically Setting Up Core Data - Where Does NSManagedObjectContext Come From?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nspersistentstore, nsmanagedobjectmodel

I want to set up Core Data entirely programmatically. I've defined a database schema in the form of an `NSManagedObjectModel` and added some entity definitions in the form of `NSEntityDescription`'s as is done at the bottom of [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdUsingMOM.html). All is well with that.

I then created an `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` using its class method `initWithObjectModel:` and passing in the aforementioned schema. At this point I don't know what to do.

I assume the next step is to somehow get an `NSManagedObjectContext`, because as I understand it, it's like a DB scratchpad and is required for most everything I want to eventually do (create,read,update,delete records, etc). What's the next step (keeping in mind no gui tools), and if it's getting a context, how do I do that? Also, if anyone knows any blog posts / resources for doing this sort of thing entirely programmatically, that'd be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to setup the `NSManagedObjectContext`:

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
```

A good step-by-step guide with explanation can be found here:

http://www.objc.io/issue-4/full-core-data-application.html

Comment: That link is a great idea!